# How to host an ASP.NET MVC project in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis, dll

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution with multiple project under it, it works fine locally after uploading the site on the server I get the **System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException** error

[image: Screenshot of the error I am getting]

I am also trying to run the solution on **IIS** and the error I am getting is **Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

I have also copied all the DLL to the output folder, what could be the issue is the problem most likely from a missing DLL, is it from the remote hosting security level or am I missing something else in the project please advise. 
[image]

**After calling the hostgator (where the site is hosted) and addressing the issue, I was told that custom DLL is not allowed in our hosting** as you may see I have taken screenshots of the DLLs I wonder what are the customs DLL in my project as hostgator technician put it

Comment: have u set copy local property of system.web.mvc dll

Comment: Application is hosted in host gator I called them they say it is of custom DLL what does that exactly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're running v3 of ASP.NET MVC. In which case, have you set the Application Pool .NET Framework version in IIS to C# 4.0? Indeed, is ASP.NET MVC and .NET Framework 4.0 installed on your server?

Does your application rely on any external libraries which were not included in the deployed application?

Are you able to debug your application at all? Ie the Application_Start. It's possible that something is going awry during that which is causing this.

Basically, more information would help!

Comment: Yes I have tried it with Visual Studio 2010 which .net 4 is included. I have also set the pool to .NET Framework v4.0.30319 in IIS.  Does the external libraries mean the projects under the solution?? I have also to say that I am very new in MVC, not that good in debugging the application.  Thanks in advance Dan.